# Huge difference in transfer speeds when using separate directories for transfer

Tags: windows, performance, file-transfer

I was transferring around 12k images (total size around 2 GBs) from my laptop running Windows 10 1909 to my Android phone via USB. Initially, it was around 5-6 images copying per second and soon after around 500 images speed began to drop and reached more than 5 seconds per image. I tried copying them in batches of 500 images but that was no better. It was like the more the number of files in a directory the slower it is to add more to it. 
Then what I did is make separate folders in the same directory and copy only about 500 images at a time to each. This way I got speeds of 5-6 images per second similar to what I was getting initially when I was transferring them all at once to a single directory. Later, I simply moved the images out of those folders using native file manager in my phone, which was almost instantaneous.
Why is that speed was decreasing exponentially when I was copying all files to the same directory?

Comment: If you say transfer via USB I assume you mean via MTP protocol. Unfortunately MTP is not a very stable protocol (well it has been developer by Microsoft do I have to say more). Therefore I would recommend not to use MTP if you want to transfer more than 100 files. Alternatively you can ZIP them without compression and extract them on device so you have to upload only 1 file. Or enable ADB in developer options and use ADB push to upload the files via USB.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and include details about the PC (OS, version, ..) you used for uploading the files? If the MTP implementation was the cause then it might be interesting for other users that use the same OS how you managed to seep-up the upload process.

Comment: I have added the OS version for reference